Script to count number of intersecting faces
I'm trying to write a script that will count the number of faces that intersect other faces in a mesh, and then print that number to the logger.
Here's a link to the .blend file that I've been using to test:
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/mqh8oncowzp0s5tuh1weh/FaceIntersect.blend?rlkey=eq9y2av91kp8wwzny0ao2ins8&st=tvqlf0m2&dl=0
There's no script in it because I removed it - all my approaches weren't working, and I'm obviously just on the wrong track and don't know what I'm doing. There are only 2 intersecting faces (as determined by the Mesh Analysis tool), at most 4 if you're counting by eye and not based off what the tool highlights, but I either get 12 (the total number of faces in the mesh), 0, 6, or 9. I got -8 once. Never 2, and never 4.
I'd appreciate any help folks may be able to offer here.

For each face corner, shoot a ray towards the next face corner and see if you hit something. Obviously you need to disregard hitting self, you can do that either by offsetting slightly from the face's plane (offset along normal by a very tiny amount) or recreate the bvhtree for each face, so that the tree doesn't contain the face doing the check. Use a loop to capture cases where a single edge goes through multiple faces. Then make sure you don't count any face twice. That should be it.

I tried this, and the first version of the script (using the bvhtree recreation method) detected 36 intersecting faces, even though the mesh only has 12 faces, and 2 of them are intersecting (I counted manually).
I tried again using the offset method, and it detected 0 intersecting faces with the same mesh.

Ah, wait, I got it figured out. Thanks!
